# Excel how to do a sort across rows to move matching content into the same columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Building a report in excel each row is a custom security group in an electronic medical record.

The first column is the security group name, these can be named anything, I need that column to stay the same. currently just alphabetical

Every following column on each row contains a security switch name.  some rows are only two columns and are over 200 columns long.
No order to these cells except the order they were added to the security group.

Is there a way to sort through all the columns of all the rows and put each control in its own so column D holds all of this security and column E holds all of that security?
Would I have to create a title row with each security getting a column?

thanks!

Comment: Assuming you can get all the column headings (your title row), Put the row and columns headings in a new worksheet. Then using `=hlookup()` should get you close. I leave it up to you to determine what additional formulas you would nest for formatting purposes.

Comment: Transpose. Sort. Transpose.

Comment: @gns100. I thought that would be the case.  I have a list of all the controls that I can sort and use.  Thank you for confirming my suspicions!